# I can't type all the information in an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

When I try to compile this small program everything is correct but when I run it I find some problems. For example, I can't type the "c" variable in the second element of the table and so on.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

struct point{
    char c;
    int x,y;
};

int main(void)
{
    int size = 4;
    struct point tp[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        printf("entrer le  nom du point no %d: ", i+1);
        tp[i].c = fgetc(stdin);
        printf("x = ");
        scanf("%d", &tp[i].x);
        printf("y = ");
        scanf("%d", &tp[i].y); 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please provide sample input, and expected output.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &tp[i].y);` --> `scanf("%d%*c", &tp[i].y);`

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of any number of the questions where `scanf()` consumes whitespace instead of the intended character.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lots of similar questions here, for example: [C scanf() and fgets() problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060573/c-scanf-and-fgets-problem), [fgets doesn't work after scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf).

You could use fgets() for user input and parse string with sscanf() for example.

Or you can use *fgetc(stdin);* after each scanf() to get rid of '\n' symbol.